# How can I append the output of this code in the TextArea?

Tags: java, netbeans

```
for (int i = 0; i < array_g.length; i++){
        int largest = i;
        for (int j = largest + 1; j < array_g.length; j++) {
            if (array_g[j] > array_g[largest]) {
                largest = j;
            }
        }
        //grades
        double temp = array_g[largest];
        array_g[largest] = array_g[i];
        array_g[i] = temp;
        //Names
        String tempString = array_n[i];
        array_n[i] = array_n[largest];
        array_n[largest] = tempString;
    }
```

I'm trying to sort different grades along with their names Highest to lowest.

Comment: After the loop is finished executing you need to create another loop that iterates through the sorted array and uses the text area `append(...)` method to add the values to the text area.

Comment: @camickr can you help me with the code? I don't have idea how to start.

Comment: And I don't have any idea what you find confusing. You already know how to use a for loop. You already know how to access an item in an array. All you need to do is write a loop that gets an item from the array and invokes `append(...)` on your text area.

Comment: @camickr sorry I get it now. Thank you